# Mobile links in an Iframe and IOS

Tags: html, ios, iphone, iframe

I was trying today to open a mobile link from one of my webapp that runs in an iframe (same domain).

It looks like these links aren't recognized by apple ?

https://plnkr.co/edit/9Rp87NcVi9Kr4MGDgIwL?p=preview

Body file

```
<html>
    <body>
        <a href="tel:1-888-888-1212">1-888-888-1212</a>
        <iframe src="iframe.html"></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

iframe.html

```
<body>
    <a href="tel:1-877-877-2323">1-877-877-2323</a>
</body>
```

In the following plunkr i made a little example of that.
My Local computer can recognize those links, both, and so does my multiple android devices. Although when it comes to IOS, nothing to be done about it, it will only work for the link that is not in an Iframe.

Anybody had a simillar problem and or knows a solution to this issue ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using a script to select the parent document from the iframe, it should work. try this:

**edit** Adding "target="_parent" to the anchor is the solution for those viewing this answer.

Dated answer:

```
<iframe  id="test" src="iframe.html"></iframe>
<script>
var iframe = document.getElementById("test");
var iDoc = iframe.contentDocument;
iDoc.write('<a target="_parent" href="tel://1-888-888-1212">1-888-888-1212</a>');
</script>
```

Comment: There was actually no need to put that in a whole script tag.
Only adding the target="_parent" to my anchor tag solved this problem

Thanks !

Comment: Glad to have helped, my framework was in zend and I had to use this script, sorry about that!

Comment: Does this work with cross-domain ? For pages which are displayed in iFrame just adding target="_parent" will do ?